# How to turn generate JSON with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I am trying to get JSON string using Oracle

My Oracle version is 12.1.0.2.0 and as I can't upgrade, I can't use  `JSON_ARRAYAGG`.

[image: The Json I want is exactly same with the picture]

Comment: For JSON support on Oracle DB's you can refer to https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A  . If your db does not support these features, you need to find a custom JSON formatter

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

A Client Based Solution, where client is [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/sqldeveloper).

Query:

```
SELECT /*json*/ ID, NAME CUST_NAME, ADDRESS,
 CURSOR(
  SELECT ACCOUNT_ID,
         NAME ACCOUNT_NAME,
         BALANCE
  FROM ACCOUNTS
  WHERE CUST.ID = CUSTOMER_ID) AS "accounts",
  '../customers/' || ID || '/pic' AS "$signature"
FROM customers cust
```

The interesting part of this is the `/*json*/` bit. That tells our script engine to take the results and format to JSON. [It also supports csv, insert statements, xml, html, etc.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/)

The query returns 3 rows from my table, and an accounts bit, which is some nested results per row via the CURSOR bit of the query.

When executed via F5 (execute as script), SQL Developer returns this JSON

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "columns":[  
            {  
               "name":"ID",
               "type":"NUMBER"
            },
            {  
               "name":"CUST_NAME",
               "type":"VARCHAR2"
            },
            {  
               "name":"ADDRESS",
               "type":"VARCHAR2"
            },
            {  
               "name":"accounts",
               "type":"REFCURSOR"
            },
            {  
               "name":"$signature",
               "type":"VARCHAR2"
            }
         ],
         "items":[  
            {  
               "id":1,
               "cust_name":"Jeff",
               "address":"101 Maple Ln",
               "accounts":[  
                  {  
                     "account_id":100,
                     "account_name":"College Fund",
                     "balance":25.99
                  },
                  {  
                     "account_id":101,
                     "account_name":"NewCar",
                     "balance":30000
                  }
               ],
               "$signature":"..\/customers\/1\/pic"
            },
            {  
               "id":2,
               "cust_name":"Kris",
               "address":"911 Pine Dr",
               "accounts":[  
                  {  
                     "account_id":200,
                     "account_name":"Checking",
                     "balance":42.25
                  },
                  {  
                     "account_id":201,
                     "account_name":"Savings",
                     "balance":64000
                  }
               ],
               "$signature":"..\/customers\/2\/pic"
            },
            {  
               "id":3,
               "cust_name":"Colm",
               "address":"404 Irish Corner",
               "accounts":[  
                  {  
                     "account_id":300,
                     "account_name":"Potatoes",
                     "balance":2500.75
                  },
                  {  
                     "account_id":301,
                     "account_name":"Speeding Tickets",
                     "balance":1900
                  }
               ],
               "$signature":"..\/customers\/3\/pic"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

We also have a mid-tier solution, [Oracle REST Data Services](http://www.oracle.com/rest). This allows you to create a RESTful Service with a GET handler to run SQL or a PL/SQL block, where the results are returned in JSON.

Comment: thanks for the assist @alex-poole - the /* always gets me

Comment: No worries, me too - usually when writing SQL\*Plus or SQL\*Loader, though I've now started escaping that \* offline which confuses people... This is nice BTW. I'm not sure the formatting options (this version and `set sqlformat`), or the SQLcl equivalents, are widely known or appreciated so it's always good when you have a chance to plug them *8-)

Comment: ps @AlexPoole we just open sourced the code that does that formatting bits, it's java and on github if you're curious https://github.com/oracle/dbtools-commons/tree/master/common

Comment: Ooh, nice. The parsing stuff looks interesting too, there have been questions about how to parse scripts into statement. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention that I am using PL/SQL developer and cant install extra software to pc that I use. Is that still possible to get JSON wit PLSQL?

Comment: @FatihKara - it is not my answer, I just did a very minor edit. But as Jeff said this is *client* functionality, so it's specific to SQL Developer (and its sibling SQLcl). As far as I know PL/SQL Developer hasn't copied it (but I don't use it).

Comment: @FatihKara I would only say or add, SQLDev is free, it comes WITH the database, and there's no 'installer' - you just unzip it.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding so thank again @thatjeffsmith

Answer (score 0):

JSON support in Oracle is pretty limited before 12.2. [This blog has posts on 4 different ways](https://jsao.io/2015/07/relational-to-json-in-oracle-database/) to generate JSON in Oracle 12.1.

The two that are relatively easy to do in plain PL/SQL are:

- [PL/JSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) (open source library)
- [APEX_JSON](https://jsao.io/2015/07/relational-to-json-with-apex_json/) (library included with Oracle APEX)